# The request body contains unexpected chracters/content for the specified content type and encoding

Tags: office365, office365api

The api url https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/rldev.onmicrosoft.com/groups does not accept utf for the displayName parameter. For example "é" "æ".

Message: The request body contains unexpected characters/content for the specified content type and encoding
Request-id d1583332-7248-48cc-827c-381f369ab77e
Date: 2015-11-12T17:50:08

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are using the correct CharSet. The default HttP charset may not work.

Comment: seems to be a comment, edit by adding some more detailed explanation.